# Let $X$ be a metric space with metrics $d, d’$ such that $d(x,y) \le d’(x,y) $ for all $x,y \in X$. Show that $\tau_d \subset \tau_{d’}$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a metric space with metrics $d, d’$ such that $d(x,y) \le d’(x,y) $ for all $x,y \in X$. Show that $\tau_d \subset \tau_{d’}$.

I need to show that for any $U \in \tau_d \implies U \in \tau_{d’}$.

Now let $U \in \tau_d$, this implies that there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x) \subset U$ is open for any $x \in U$. Now $B_\varepsilon(x)  = \{y \in U : d(x,y) < \varepsilon \}$, but by assumption we have that $d(x,y) \le d’(x,y).$ So $B_\varepsilon(x)  = \{y \in U : d(x,y) \le d’(x,y) \}$.

I’m not sure how to go further from here. It doesn’t seem that the last line implies that $U \in \tau_{d’}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{y:d'(x,y) <\epsilon\} \subseteq \{y:d(x,y) <\epsilon\}\subseteq U$. So for each $x \in U$ there is an open ball in $(X,d')$ containing $x$ and contained In $U$.  This implies that $U \in \tau_{d'}$.

Comment: [+1]. Another way to formulate this is to say that $\mathrm I_d: (X,d')\to(X,d)$ is continuous (because $1$-Lipschitzian).

Comment: Should the sets be the other way around in the first line?

Comment: @Georgi No, $d'(x,y) <\epsilon$ implies $d(x,y) \leq d'(x,y) <\epsilon$, so what I have written is correct.